# Python Subprocess call() File Not Found Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I wanted to create a Minecraft Launcher using Python today, but the game cannot be started. As I can see, the subprocess.call() line gives an error.

My Code:

```
import minecraft_launcher_lib
import subprocess

minecraft_directory = "C:\\Users\\Mert KAPLANDAR\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft"

options = minecraft_launcher_lib.utils.generate_test_options()

minecraft_command = minecraft_launcher_lib.command.get_minecraft_command("1.8.9", minecraft_directory, options)

subprocess.call(minecraft_command)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mert KAPLANDAR\Desktop\launcher.py", line 10, in <module>
    subprocess.call(str(minecraft_command))
  File "C:\Users\Mert KAPLANDAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Mert KAPLANDAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Mert KAPLANDAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor
```

Is there an alternative that I can use instead of the subprocess.call() function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of double slashes, try setting the path as a raw string.

i.e.:
`minecraft_directory = r"C:\Users\Mert KAPLANDAR\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft"`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. The problem is not already there. subprocess.call() gives this error for values ​​from minecraft_command. You can run the code and experience

Comment: Reading through the documentation, I see you need to install the version of Minecraft at that directory. Maybe try this doing this?

```minecraft_launcher_lib.install.install_minecraft_version("1.8.9", minecraft_directory)```